# @Mention Random user discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hy everybody,so I have been trying to write a code in which discord bot mentions random user from my server ,I have written the code but the bot keeps mentioning itself

```
from random import choice

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def best(ctx):
    user = choice(ctx.message.channel.guild.members)
    await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} is the best player')
```

Comment: Have you tried checking how many members there are in that variable?

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to isolate the problem. For example, does `ctx.message.channel.guild.members` have the value you expect it to have?

Answer (score 1):

You must put random.choice instead of choice

```py
user = random.choice(ctx.message.channel.guild.members)
```

The random.choice will choose a random user. Choice just do nothing